# 0xc000007b Error - but all DLLs are 32 bit

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, clr

I am compiling my C++ code with /clr option using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7 32 bit OS targeting .NET Framework 3.5.

All the DLLs are 32 bit (verified using Dependency Walker).

As per my research this error comes up when 32 bit code calls 64 bit DLLs but this not the case here.

Are there any other root causes of error 0xc000007b?

Comment: A DLL targeting a completely different machine architecture, like Itanium.  Do you at least know the troublemaker DLL?  Look in the Output window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just happened to resolve this issue. 
It seems that this error is *not only* caused by mixing 64 bit libraries in 32 bit code but also when libraries are messed up - in my case I was using binary PCRE library.

I built PCRE myself using MingW and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For use .NET FW 4.0, you should use legacy activation shim code to load .NET FW as COM component 
into your hosting app, like this:

Use macro

```
#define LEGACY_ACTIVATION_SHIM_ALLOW_LEGACY_API_FALLBACK
```

**Sudoku.Runtime.h:**

```
#pragma once
// 
extern "C" int wWinMainCRTStartup();
```

**Sudoku.Runtime.cpp:**

```
// Sudoku.Runtime.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

int _runtime()
{
    wWinMainCRTStartup();
    return 0;
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    try
    {
        //CoInitializeEx(NULL, 0);              
        //CoUninitialize();
        HRESULT hr;     
        ICorRuntimeHost *pHost = NULL;
        hr = LegacyActivationShim::CorBindToRuntimeEx(NULL, NULL, STARTUP_LOADER_OPTIMIZATION_MULTI_DOMAIN_HOST, CLSID_CorRuntimeHost, IID_ICorRuntimeHost, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&pHost));
        if (!FAILED(hr))
        {
            IUnknown *pAppDomainPunk = NULL;
            hr = pHost->CreateDomainEx(TEXT("_runtime"), NULL, NULL, &pAppDomainPunk);
            if (!FAILED(hr))
            {
                _::_AppDomain *pDefaultDomain = NULL;
                hr = pAppDomainPunk->QueryInterface(__uuidof(_::_AppDomain), reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&pDefaultDomain));
                if (!FAILED(hr))
                {
                    _::_ObjectHandle *pObjHandle = NULL;
                    hr = pDefaultDomain->CreateInstance(_bstr_t("Sudoku"), _bstr_t("Sudoku.Runtime"), &pObjHandle); 
                    if (!FAILED(hr))
                    {
                        VARIANT v;
                        VariantInit(&v);
                        hr = pObjHandle->Unwrap(&v);
                        if (!FAILED(hr))
                        {
                            _::IRuntime *pRemotingHost = NULL;
                            hr = v.pdispVal->QueryInterface(__uuidof(_::IRuntime), (void**) &pRemotingHost);    
                            if (!FAILED(hr))
                            {
                                ::System::Reflection::Assembly^ ra = Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly();
                                array<::System::Byte>^ bytes = ra->GetName()->GetPublicKeyToken();
                                SAFEARRAY *psa = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_UI1, 0, bytes->Length);
                                BYTE *pData;
                                hr = SafeArrayAccessData(psa, (void **)&pData);
                                if (!FAILED(hr))
                                {
                                    for(int i=0; i < bytes->Length; i++) pData[i] = bytes[i];
                                    hr = SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa);
                                    if (!FAILED(hr))
                                    {
                                        pRemotingHost->Run(psa);
                                    }
                                    pHost->UnloadDomain(pAppDomainPunk);
                                }
                            }
                            pObjHandle->Release();
                        }
                        pDefaultDomain->Release();
                    }
                    pAppDomainPunk->Release();
                }
                pHost->Release();
            }
            LegacyActivationShim::CorExitProcess(0);
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**stdafx.h:**

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"
// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here

// Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
#define VC_EXTRALEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN   

#import <mscorlib.tlb> auto_rename \
    rename("value", "___value") \
    rename("ReportEvent", "___ReportEvent") \
    rename_namespace("_") \
    raw_interfaces_only \
    high_property_prefixes("_get","_put","_putref")

#import "..\\Public\\Sudoku.tlb" auto_rename \
    rename_namespace("_") \
    raw_interfaces_only \
    high_property_prefixes("_get","_put","_putref")

// C RunTime Header Files
#include <tchar.h>

#include "cor.h"
#include "mscoree.h"
#include "strongname.h"

#include "Sudoku.Runtime.h"
#include "AssemblyInfo.h"
#include "Resource.h"


#define LEGACY_ACTIVATION_SHIM_ALLOW_LEGACY_API_FALLBACK

#include "LegacyActivationShimDelayLoad.h"
```

**LegacyActivationShim.h:**

```
// ==++==
// 
//   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// 
// ==--==
//
// LegacyActivationShim.h
//
// This file allows simple migration from .NET Runtime v2 Host Activation APIs
// to the .NET Runtime v4 Host Activation APIs through simple shim functions.
// To use, just include this header file after the header file that declares the
// deprecated APIs you are using, and append the "LegacyActivationShim::" namespace
// in front of all deprecated API calls.
//
// For example,
//      #include "mscoree.h"
//      ...
//      CorBindToRuntimeEx(
//          NULL, NULL, 0, CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost, IID_ICLRRuntimeHost, (LPVOID *)&pRH));
// becomes
//      #include "mscoree.h"
//      #include "LegacyActivationShim.h"
//      ...
//      LegacyActivationShim::CorBindToRuntimeEx(
//          NULL, NULL, 0, CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost, IID_ICLRRuntimeHost, (LPVOID *)&pRH));
//
// To enable fallback to the legacy APIs when v4.0 is not installed on the machine,
// define LEGACY_ACTIVATION_SHIM_ALLOW_LEGACY_API_FALLBACK before including this
// header file.
//
// To use the legacy API fallback in a delay-loaded fashion, include LegacyActivationShimDelayLoad.h
// instead.
//
```

**Sudoku.Runtime.cs:**

```
[Serializable]
[ComVisible(true)]
[Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]
public class Runtime : IRuntime
{    
    public void Run(byte[] publikKeyToken)
    {
        Application.Run(publikKeyToken);
    }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]
public interface IRuntime
{
    void Run(byte[] publikKeyToken);
}
```